# Rerun activity in Azure Data Factory V2 using .net sdk

Tags: c#, .net, azure, sdk, azure-data-factory

I am trying to rerun activity in Azure Data Factory as in this article - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/rerun-activities-inside-your-data-factory-pipelines/
There is manually example, but I want provide this process automatically using .net sdk. Could you provide examples, links or any information how to rerun activities using .net sdk

Thank you for any help or suggestions!

Comment: Have you read this article? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-dot-net

Comment: @TấnNguyên Yes, I have used .net sdk for creating Data Factory, running pipelines and other. But I don't know how to rerun pipeline from failed activity.

Comment: yes then after created pipeline, then you could send [REST API to run it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers). I'm not google the fail status which could retrieve from DF yet, but when it failed, it might workaround by storing the log, or the status to the blob then you could trigger them.

Comment: @TấnNguyên thanks for your answer, it can help in my feature solution, but I wanna understand, can I rerun pipeline from failed activity using **SDK** like in this article with manually example - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/rerun-activities-inside-your-data-factory-pipelines/ . Man in video sad that we can do this, but I can't find any examples or documentation about rerun using **SDK**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know your concern, the activity could be rerun based on the statement in the video clearly. So,you definitely know how to do the operations in the [ADF UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-visually).

If you refer to the [source code reference of ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory?view=azure-dotnet),you can't find any methods related to Activity Run.

[image]

In fact, it is set up by the `startActivityName` property in the [IPipelinesOperations.CreateRunWithHttpMessagesAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory.ipipelinesoperations.createrunwithhttpmessagesasync?view=azure-dotnet) method.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.